# Crystal Reports 8 - Error 533 PESStartPrintJob

Tags: windows, crystal-reports, delphi

We have on the company I work for an application built in Delphi V with Crystal Reports 8.

We all know that Crystal & Delphi can be temperamental sometimes and the worst thing is, nearly no detail on the error. Also there is a big lack of documentation on the web about this. There's lot of people with similar issue but no solution.

The error I'm talking about in particular is the one on the image below. This happens when trying to print any Crystal Reports on screen.

[image: Error 533]

This has happened sometimes in the clients computer and it was hard for us to replicate on our environment. Since it's an old version of Crystal it is very hard to find any helpful documentation to know the exact source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the registry than can be cause by a double installation of BDE. This can happen for several reasons:

- Reinstalled the application or borland without uninstalling it before
- The uninstall was not fully completed
- Installed a second application using BDE

To verify this, I went into the registry and found the following:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Borland \ Database Engine] "DLLPath" = "C: \ \ Program Files \ \ Common Files \ \ Borland Shared \ \ BDE" in the form of path1, path2.

Now in order to fix this, you need to do the following:

- Make a backup of the BDE Key in case anything goes wrong.
- Close your application.
- Open Regedit (Start> Run> regedit.exe)
- Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Borland \ Database Engine
- Then double click on the key DLLPath editing and 1 of the 2 pathways (Check which is the correct one according to your installation). You should have two paths like in the image below. Remove one of them

[image: Registry with two paths]

This should have only one path like in the image below.

[image: Registry with one path]

Close RegEdit

Now you can reopen your application and try to open any report on screen. If you've followed the simple steps correctly you shouldn't get any error and you should be able to see the reports on screen.

This happened particularly in my application, but the same process needs to be followed on applications using Crystal Reports and BDE Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have this kind of error with Crystal 8.5, was related to mixed versions of Crystal deploy DLLs or the absence of them. In my case with Crystal 6.0 that some of our customers still use.

The boring part is find all the DLLs and delete them. Generally they will be on %systemroot%\system32 on x86 and on %systemroot%\syswow64 on x64 systems.

Other things to be aware of:

- Set up a starting point, I mean, here we always make sure it works on a clean machine.
- Multiple version of Crystal Reports on the same machine simple does not work, period. No matter if you are talking about the development or deployment environment.
- I generally put all Crystal 8.5 deployment DLLs under %systemroot%\crystal and put it on the system PATH. That resolved me 95% of most common deploy related problems.

I know it a bit late to answer, but it could help others.